# fast deletion of a line with an index from a file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a HUGE file of 10G. I want to remove line 188888 from this file.

I use sed as follows:

```
sed -i '188888d' file
```

The problem is it is really slow. I understand it is because of the size of the file, but is there any way that I can do that faster.

Thanks

Comment: Are all the lines the same length, or is the line length calculable by line number? Because if it's not, *every byte before the line* has to be read.

Comment: Lines have different length...

Comment: Then the answer to your question is no, unfortunately.

Comment: I kinda disagree, Why wc -l is much faster than that? It basically does the same operation right?

Comment: If I do head and tail and put them together, it will be faster than that...

Comment: I have no idea what `wc` does and I only know a bit about `sed` so I can't tell you. But it is impossible to do much optimization, if any. `sed` is probably slower because it has to parse the command.

Comment: wc -l is much faster because you're only reading the file, not rewriting it back to disk. Writing to disk is always orders of mag slower than reading. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed -i '188888{;d;q;}' file
```

You may need to experiment with which of the above semi-colons you keep, `{d;q} ...` being the 2nd thing to try.

This will stop searching the file after it deletes that one line, but you'll still have to spend the time re-writing the file. It would also be worth testing

```
sed '188888{;q;d;}' file > /path/to/alternate/mountpoint/newFile
```

where the alternate mountpoint is on a separate disk drive.

**final edit**
Ah, one other option would be to edit the file while it is being written through a pipe

```
 yourLogFileProducingProgram | sed -i '188888d' > logFile
```

But this assumes that you know that the data your want to delete is always at line '188888, is that possible?

I hope this helps.

Comment: See edit 30 secs ago. Per other's comments, you can't even write a custom C program, because the random and variable line lengths make it impossible to caclulate an offset (and in any case, the most time is re-writing the file). Sed is small exe footprint compared to any other scripting language or java and that paradigm. Is this a one-time issue, or are you talking about a repeating problem. If repeating, then it is definitely worth the time trying to find the fastest solution, otherswise sed is probably your best bet. Good luck!

Comment: final edit above. final comment, you may want it to go faster, but writing a 10M file takes a long time. Can you rethink your strategy on logfiles? make a newone every hr, or 10 mins or ?? per your application. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The file lines are determined by counting the \n character, if the line size are variable then you cannot calculate the offset to the location given a line but have to count the number of newlines.

This will always be O(n) where n is the number of bytes in the file.

Parallel algorithms does not help either because this operation is disk IO limited, divide and conquer will be even slower.

If you will do this a lot on a same file, there are ways to preprocess the file and make it faster.

A easy way is to build a index with

```
line#:offset
```

And when you want to find a line, do binary search (Log n) in index for the line number you want, and use the offset to locate the line in the original file.